# While with 2 conditions and convert str to int

Tags: python

I'm new at coding and I have a school excercise but honestly I need your help. I have this code on python and it works until I use numbers but if the user just press enter, the program doesn't requires a number and what I need is to create a while for numbers <1 and for ' '.

I  tried using other options but it shows me an error indicating that ' ' couldn't be converted to float, I guees is not as easier as just saying `while InvX==" "`: but i first have to convert ' ' to flot but i just don't know how. Please help.

```
Inv1 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 1 ")));
while Inv1<1:
  print("El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0")
  Inv1 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 1 ")));
Inv2 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 2 ")));
while Inv2<1:
  print("El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0")
  Inv2 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 2 ")));
Inv3 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 3 ")));
while Inv3<1:
  print("El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0")
  Inv3 = (float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 3 ")));
Capital=Inv1+Inv2+Inv3
Rep1=(Inv1*100)/Capital
Rep2=(Inv2*100)/Capital
Rep3=(Inv3*100)/Capital
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 1 equivale al ", Rep1,"% del capital total")
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 2 equivale al ", Rep2,"% del capital total")
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 3 equivale al ", Rep3,"% del capital total")
```

How can i solve this, please?

I tried creating at least to while for every Inv, when I use 0 the code returns to ask that i must use a positive number but if I press enter (without any number" an error is shown sayin "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but if I press enter (without any number" an error is shown sayin "ValueError: could not convert string to float"" What do you think should happen instead with that input? How can a number be created, if the string is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by defining your variables at the start of your code to run the `while` loops before the user has input anything. You can make use of [exception handling](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) (`try:` and `except:`) to catch the `ValueError` and prompt the user to input something else.

```
#define variables
Inv1 = 0
Inv2 = 0
Inv3 = 0

#loop while less than 1 or not float
while Inv1 <= 0 or not isinstance(Inv1, float):
    try:
        #get input & convert to float
        Inv1 = float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 1 "))
        
        #if input was not greater than 0
        if Inv1 <= 0 : print('El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0')
        
    except:
        #if input was not float
        print('Please enter a number')

#loop while less than 1 or not float
while Inv2 <= 0 or not isinstance(Inv2, float):
    try:
        #get input & convert to float
        Inv2 = float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 2 "))

        #if input was not greater than 0
        if Inv2 <= 0 : print('El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0')
        
    except:
        #if input was not float
        print('Please enter a number')

#loop while less than 1 or not float
while Inv3 <= 0 or not isinstance(Inv3, float):
    try:
        #get input & convert to float
        Inv3 = float(input("Indique el monto a invertir por el inversionista 3 "))

        #if input was not greater than 0
        if Inv3 <= 0 : print('El aporte del inversionista debe ser mayor a 0')
        
    except:
        #if input was not float
        print('Please enter a number')
        
#calculate percentages
Capital = Inv1 + Inv2 + Inv3

Rep1 = (Inv1*100) / Capital
Rep2 = (Inv2*100) / Capital
Rep3 = (Inv3*100) / Capital

#output solution
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 1 equivale al ", Rep1,"% del capital total")
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 2 equivale al ", Rep2,"% del capital total")
print ("El capital aportado por el inversionista 3 equivale al ", Rep3,"% del capital total")
```

Since you mentioned you are new to coding, I will give you a few tips. Try to format the code to improve readability by separating parts that perform different operations. Another good habit to get into early is to leave comments by starting the line with `#`. This makes it much easier for others to interpret your code and also for your future self to remember what a certain part of it does. Typically, it is also good practice to define all variables at the start of your code.

EDITS: Removed excess semicolons & corrected errors (it's late and I'm tired)

Comment: Why all of the semi-colons in Python?

Comment: @Chris Good catch I'm not used to writing in Python. Edited.

Comment: Small typo -  your second while loop is checking `Inv1 <= 0` instead of `Inv2 <= 0`

Comment: Why `isinstance(Inv1, float):`? How do you expect `Inv1` to be something different than a `float` when you do `Inv1 = float(...)` in the loop?

Comment: The repetition of the code blocks just calls for a function.